# Formatting grep output with blank line between two occurrences

Tags: bash, grep

I'm looking to format my output this way, but with appropriate, more graceful code.

In file:

```
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence
line with bar occurence
line with bar occurence
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence
```

My bash command:

```
cat file | grep -e foo && printf '\n' && cat file | grep -e bar
```

And result:

```
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence

line with bar occurence
line with bar occurence
```

Comment: With `sed`: `sed -n '/foo/p; /bar/H; ${g; p}' file`

Comment: Nice one @Cyrus ;-) One day I should learn how to use `sed` cycles and buffers for real

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `paste` command with `grep`

```
paste -zd'\n' <(grep 'foo' input_file) <(grep 'bar' input_file)
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence
line with foo occurence

line with bar occurence
line with bar occurence
```

Comment: Nice approach! The only issue is that output contains a nul byte at the end.

Answer (score 0):

How about running the `grep` command in a loop:

```sh
for term in foo bar
do
    grep $term file
    echo  # Add a blank line
done
```

The above as a one-liner:

```sh
for term in foo bar; do grep $term file; echo; done
```

Comment: I suspect that the output contains a blank line at the end.

Comment: Yes, the output will contain a blank line at the end.